# A Baffling Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

My prefix will make you shiver and shake
My infix is when you hesitate
My suffix is as strong as could be
My whole will baffle you totally.

Comment: Just went through synonyms of baffle on a site and found the answer.

Comment: @prit.patel aaw shame you didn't answer though.

Comment: That's because when I saw your question it was already answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> **flummox**.

My prefix will make you shiver and shake

> The **flu**.

My infix is when you hesitate

> The utterance **umm**.

My suffix is as strong as could be

> Strong like an **ox**.

My whole will baffle you totally.

> To **flummox** is to *baffle*.

Comment: Well done! I knew it was easy but I didn't think anyone would get it that quickly.

Comment: @Astralbee The clues were direct, which can be good for ensuring uniqueness of an answer but also makes solving easier. Perhaps incorporating more [tag:riddle] and [tag:wordplay] can add those little interesting twists. (The tag info for both tags also list good techniques for achieving this.)

Comment: Well that is helpful, thank you. My last few puzzles have all required several clues before anyone got them so I deliberately made this a little easier.

Comment: @Astralbee Finding the right difficulty balance is not easy but will come with practice :)